# Как оптимизировать чат на XHR

Tags: php

Вообщем сделал чат на XHR все работает... Но! у меня php скрипт, на который ссылается запрос работает в цикле и вообщем выдает ошибку что скрипт работает больше 30 секунд, я выключил репорт ошибок, поставил максимальное выполнение скрипта на 600 секунд и сейчас вроде все нормально, но это ведь не самый лучший метод решения этой проблемы? Или по другому никак?

Comment: В 2016 году чаты принято делать на вебсокетах (и не на пхп)

Comment: Альтернитивный вариант оптимизировать php скрипт, но это считается плохой практикой. Обычно дешевле докупить 300 серверов чтобы обслуживать запросы, чем выделить время и деньги программисту на оптимизацию.

Comment: andreymal, Да, но мне кажется это сути не поменяет сильно, что тут надо постоянно проверять новые сообщения, что на сокетах

Comment: php умеет с сокетами работать: [первая ссылка на хабр в гугле](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/).

Comment: @Thread Значит вы не разбираетесь в асинхронщине и событийно-ориентированном программировании :)

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос, сильно ли грузит систему скрипт проверки сообщений чата php и сильна ли эта разница с сокетами?

Comment: Как по-вашему, что компьютеру делать проще: постоянно делать запросы в базу на предмет новых сообщений, или же в момент получения очередного сообщения сразу передавать его получателям?

Comment: Хотя да, это вы правы... Но черт подери сколько вещей придется переписать

Answer (score 0):

Лучше ещё возвращайте пустой ответ если скрипт выполняется дольше определённого лимита — для этого задаёте константу максимального времени. При начале обработки ответа делаете замер текущего времени, а потом в цикле проверяете и если текущее время выполнения больше максимального из константы, то возвращаете пустой ответ или пустую структуру.

Comment: @Naumov но общепринятый и юзаемый всеми, long polling называется

Comment: @andreymal да это троль за мной увязался просто

Comment: @andreymal если назвать кастыль общепринятым он не станет решением. Так как кастыль - это решение которое не позволяет упасть приложению и маскирует баги. Решение заплатка. Все симптомы на лицо.

Comment: @Naumov предложите своё решение. Long polling решает свои задачи и используется на крупных ресурсах.

Comment: Какие задачи? Какие ресурсы?

Comment: @Naumov например вконтакте юзает в лонгполлинг для апи. Или сий ресурс для вас слишком мелкий?

Comment: @Naumov vk, fb, яндекс, google. Каждый развил идею в свою сторону и под себя использует, но суть одна и таже